# Only last row data of html table is being posted in controller

Tags: php, html

I am creating rows of HTML table like this

```
    <?php foreach($products as $key=>$val) { ?>
            <tr class="tr_entry">
            <td><input class="input_entry" id="no" name="no" type="text"></td>
                <td>
                    <select id = "stage" name="stage">
                        <option value="1">01</option>
                        <option value="2">02</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
</tr>
    <?php } ?>
```

and posting this form in a controller using "post" method. In controller I am using this

```
print_r($_POST);exit;
```

but I am getting only data of last row of table. Need help.

Comment: You should use `array inputs`. Rather then defining like this `name="stage"` try this `name="stage[]"`

Comment: yes now i am getting data but can i also achieve the thing that in one array i get data of one row?

Comment: and how will i be able to save this in data base when values of each row are in different array

Comment: You can try this simple example with a basic input https://eval.in/892090 , after having each row in different array, you can iterate over it and insert in database and that's it.

Comment: that is absolutely working fine, what if i have 3-4 other simple input fields also,how to handle them?

Comment: Can you share your input fields/data?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158135/discussion-between-sahil-gulati-and-dan).

Answer (score 0):

For all the iterations of for loop  your  input's name are same.For each iteration of for loop, old values are replaced by new values,so 
at the end for loop  you will get values of last tr of the table.

Use below code to get all the inputs in form.

```
<?php foreach($products as $key=>$val) { ?>
            <tr class="tr_entry">
            <td><input class="input_entry" id="no" name="no<?php echo $key ?>" type="text"></td>
                <td>
                    <select id = "stage" name="stage<?php echo $key ?>">
                        <option value="1">01</option>
                        <option value="2">02</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
</tr>
    <?php } ?>
```